# Material-ui theme parent component but not child component of same type

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to style a Material UI Expansion Panel so that my theme is applied only to the parent expansion panel when expanded, but not any nested panels within it.

For example:

[image]

Here is my theme:

```js
const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiExpansionPanelSummary: {
      root: {
        minHeight: "0px",
        minWidth: "0px",
        "&$expanded": {
          backgroundColor: "lightblue"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get this style to only apply to parent ExpansionPanelSummary components and not any ExpansionPanelSummary components that exist inside of another ExpansionPanel.

Here is a sandbox example:
[image: Edit MUI How to: Override Tab Theme]

Comment: The theme is probably less important that the implementation. You might want a boolean controlling it in your component, defaulting to false, and then opt-in on the parent.

Comment: My only issue with doing it that way is scaleability. There are too many expansion panels in this project for this to be the best solution. Also, I'm not sure how it would opt in/out of the theme since it appears to be global for the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one way to do this:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core";

const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiExpansionPanelSummary: {
      root: {
        minHeight: "0px",
        minWidth: "0px",
        "&$expanded": {
          backgroundColor: "lightblue"
        },
        ".MuiExpansionPanelDetails-root &$expanded": {
          backgroundColor: "transparent"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

export default myTheme;
```

[image: Edit custom ExpansionPanelSummary theme]